# hbase scanner .next() returns null

Tags: java, servlets, if-statement, for-loop, hbase

I'm scanning the hbase for md5 string and I have to perform some actions, if there are strings found.
The problem is, that if I check it first time, it returns true (and at log is the value), but then, when I use same expression in if or for statement I got a false result.

```
        Scan scanCookiesData = new Scan();

        scanCookiesData.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("md5data"), Bytes.toBytes("md5data"));
        ResultScanner scannerCookiesData = dbHelper.getTable("userInfo").getScanner(scanCookiesData);
            if (scannerCookiesData.next() != null) {
            response.getWriter().println("if (scannerCookiesData.next() != null)");

            for (Result r = scannerCookiesData.next(); r != null; r = scannerCookiesData.next()) {
                response.getWriter().println("INSIDE FOR!!!");

                if (md5data.equals(Bytes.toString(r.value()))) {
                    // Here we will assign ID to the user.
                    response.getWriter().println(assignID(Bytes.toString(r.value())));
                    response.setStatus(200);
                } else {
                    response.getWriter().println("ELSE");
                }
            }
        } else {
            response.getWriter().println(createNewUser(json));
            response.setStatus(200);
        }
```

In this code, at first if it gets "true", but in for is not invoked, as it will show "false".. but scanner is not a null (in db is that md5 string), so it should get "true"..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best reason I can think of right now is just 1 result being found for your query. The error is in that cased of a misunderstanding of calling `next()` on your side: That call returns the next value (if any exists) and moves one step ahead, with no way to go *back*.

By calling `if (scannerCookiesData.next() != null)` you actually retrieve that result, and skip over to the next one (if any exists). 
This means that you never actually used your first result, except for the null check, as it is stored nowhere. By the time you reach your `for` loop you would start working with the second result, which I assume just doesn't exist in your case.

When no further result is found for a scanner, `null` will be returned instead of a `Result` object, signalizing the end of your result set.

Comment: Yes, I thought about this scenario, and I guess it is the case. If I take of first if-statement and leave only for-loop, then servlet crashes when there are no results found...

Comment: I rerited my code:
`
           Result rr = scannerCookiesData.next();
            if (rr != null) {
                if (md5data.equals(Bytes.toString(rr.value()))) {
                    // Here we will assign ID to the user.
                    response.getWriter().println(assignID(Bytes.toString(rr.value())));
                    response.setStatus(200);
                }
            } else {
                response.getWriter().println(createNewUser(json));
                response.setStatus(200);
            }
`
But problem will be if it founds more than one same string (but it shouldn't)

Comment: Yeah, might as well do that. If you check for a md5 checksum in your DB there hopefully should only be one result anyway, or you have to find out a way to handle collisions ;)